# How do I support AMP-html and desktop HTML simultaneously

Tags: amp-html

As I understand about the amp, the amp is only for mobile devices. If I'm using responsive design, my web server provides same HTML document per page for every device.

But If I want to use the AMP, the web server should decide whether it provide HTML for desktop or it provide HTML for AMP.

How do I do that? By `User-Agent`?(I think it is ugly and not scalable)
I missed something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have two urls for the same content. The main article would be 
    http://example.com/my-article
and the amp version :
    http://example.com/my-article.amp

there's no user-agent switching for the same url. You just have to specify in the main article that you have a amp version of the document with a link tag :

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://example.com/my-article.amp" >
```

and in the amp version specify the address of the main content with a canonical :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/my-article" >
```

To answer your question, the actual "mobile detection" is sort of done in the search results page as it is google who will determine what link to show to the user.

Answer (score 3):

If the AMP format and [extensions](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/extensions) support all the features that your page requires, you can publish only the AMP version. To make it look good on desktops (or wide-screen devices in general), make sure to limit the maximum width of the page using the `max-width` CSS property:

```css
body > div {
    max-width: 85em;
}
```

For an example, look at [LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/science/la-sci-sn-drug-mimics-opioids-20160817-snap-story,amp.html).

[image: Limiting maximum AMP article with]

... or [The Guardian](https://amp.theguardian.com/us-news/commentisfree/2016/feb/16/thomas-piketty-bernie-sanders-us-election-2016):

[image: The Guardian limits width to 600px]

Comment: You offer a very good example, but in the Guardian Case, they offer a Mobile + AMP + Desktop versions, each one with their particularities, minor changes on design and some big different areas, like related content and comments, so, in the end, seems that the industry is taking an approach to offer the best experience on each case (ditching responsive options), even when you have to maintain different version of your site (and don’t get me started with FB instant articles)